# Connect-AzAccount "The connection for this site is not secure" error

Tags: azure, authentication, localhost, azure-powershell

I am using `Connect-AzAccount` to login with Azure PowerShell. First I am brought to this page with a URL like this. I then select my account and continue. It does not prompt me for my password because of what I assume is SSO.

```http
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=https%3a%2f%2fmanagement.core.windows.net%2f%2f.default+openid+profile+offline_access&response_type=code&
client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&
redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a8400%2f&
claims=%7b%22access_tokenXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXvaluesXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&
client-request-id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&
x-client-SKU=MSAL.NetCore&
x-client-Ver=4.49.1.0&
x-client-CPU=x64&
x-client-OS=Microsoft+Windows+10.0.22621&
prompt=select_account&
code_challenge=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&
code_challenge_method=S256&
state=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_info=1&sso_nonce=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&mscrid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&login_hint=MYNAME%40EMAIL.com
```

[image]

Then I brought to this page where I am facing the error.

```http
https://localhost:8400/?code=XXXXXXXXXXX
&client_info=XXXXXX
&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
&session_state=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

[image]

Comment: I believe it has something to do with Edge browser settings. Please search for `Edge automatic https redirection` and you will find different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Need to check below:**

- Before attempting to authenticate again, clear your browser's cache and cookies.
- Update the Az module using `Update-Module -Name Az`.
- Check to see if any firewalls are preventing access to the redirect URL or the local host that you are using.
- The redirect URI in your App registration should match the `redirect_uri` argument in your PowerShell authentication request  (`http/https` and `port number`, if appropriate).
- Try authenticating using different browser if `Edge` is not working.

After checking all the above, I tried connecting to `Az` account with the relevant
`connect-AzAccount` command and it worked as shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: authenticating with `edge inprivate` worked. just had to copy the URL that came from the `edge` pop window that opens when first running the command.

Comment: So is it working now? @greg

Comment: yes @Jahnavi it is